# error while adding service reference in c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf-binding

I am using VS 2017 with .net framework 4.5.1 and trying to add third party wcf wsdl in project where the service uses tls12 protocol.

while adding the service getting following error
[image]

I have also tried with custom binding and getting the below error.
"Unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. OSB-380001"

I also added the proxy configuration in Web.config. Still no luck.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy autoDetect="Unspecified" usesystemdefault="False" bypassonlocal="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: One possibility is that the service is old ASMX service and we need to use Web reference, which is located in the Add Service reference menu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have tried as suggested, still getting "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

Comment: emm, How do you ensure that the service works properly and the service WSDL address is correct?

Comment: The same works properly, when I access from SOAP UI.